# I need an efficient method to combine thousands of csv files

Tags: shell, csv

I asked the same question on stackoverflow, but did not get a satisfactory answer.

I have a directory tree like this:

```
bacteria > species(num subdirs = 1300) > kmer(num subsudirs = 9)
```

The directory and subdirectories are agruped this way:

```
bacteria/specie1/kmer2/csv
                    kmer3/csv
                    .
                    .
                    kmer9/csv

         specie2/kmer2/csv
                    kmer3/csv
                    .
                    .
                    kmer9/csv

         specie1300/kmer2/csv
                    kmer3/csv
                    .
                    .
                    kmer9/csv
```

In the kmer subdirectory there are the csv files and depend on the species it has 1 or many files.

The csv files are simple, two coulmns with the kmer and it counts. **I really dont know if all bigger kmers (like 6 or upper) will have the same
kmer keys, because this I am counting them**.

For example:

```
bacteria/species1/kmer2/example_csv_k2_count.csv
```

The csv example_csv_k2_count.csv has this structure:

```
kmer,count
AA, 10
AC, 20
.
.
.
```

For each species and kmer counts I need to concatenate the csv files in one master csv for each kmer count (2-9).
For example for subdiretories of all species with kmer2 counts I need

```
specie1.csv1
kmer, count
aa, 22
at, 21...

specie1.csv2
kmer, count
aa, 31 
at, 18...
```

For bacteria/species2/kmer2:

```
specie2.csv1
kmer, count
aa, 22
at, 21...

specie2.csv2
kmer, count
aa, 31 
at, 18...
```

I need a make a master kmer2_count.csv for each species and they kmer counts:

```
kmer, count
    aa, 22, 31,...
    at, 21, 18,...
```

I tried many codes and commands that I search in stack, google, but I always get they stacked:

```
kmer, count
    aa, 31 
    at, 18...
kmer, count
    aa, 22
    at, 21...
```

Example of shell commands I tried:

```
    $ cat */kmer2/*.csv | datamash -t , transpose
    datamash: transpose input error: line 275 has 1 fields (previous lines had 2);
```

Ex2:

```
 awk '
            FNR==1 && NR!=1 { while (/^<header>/) getline; }
            1 {print}
        ' */kmer9/*.csv > ex.csv
```

Now I am using python/pandas and got the job working but for kmer counts bigger than 6, ex 7 my notebook is working for 3 days in a roll.
I am trying to merge this to make a mean of counts because many species had they genome sequenced many times or because they are subspecies or strains. Than I will make a master file with the mean of all sequenced genomes.

Because this I would love a shell solution.

Thanks,
Paulo

PS = Sorry about the bad text explaining my needs.
Hope now it get more clear.
My apologies

Comment: I don't understand the numbers: I see 1300, 9 and 1-12000. Two questions at the CSV output level: [A] Will all files have exactly the same kmer keys (aa, at, etc), or what happens when some files have an extra one like aq, or are missing an aa (which would cause ragged lines -- not all rows having the same number of columns). That's where your transpose error is arising. [B] Are you really proposing to output CSV rows with 12,000 columns? What would you expect to use to process those?

Comment: Are the fields in your CSV files really delimited by a comma _and a space_? Why have you added spaces to the first fields in the resulting CSV files?  Joining (not stacking) CSV files is easy with csvjoin, but it only handles properly formatted CSV files.  Also address Paul_Pendant's issues.

Comment: This question is not clear, and needs some editing.

Comment: your output file seems to be bogus: if the header is `kmer,count`, you should have exactly 2 columns, not one per input file.

Comment: And to be able to use tools that deal with proper CSV formats, you could first pre-process all the files to format the properly.

Comment: my csv files have all the same structure 2 coluns and all sep is a ',' no spaces anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to have understood your goal.

If you need to pass from

```
cat input1.csv
kmer,count
aa,22
at,21

cat input2.csv
kmer,count
aa,31 
at,18
```

to

something like

```
kmer,count
aa,22;31
at,21;18
```

you can use [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and run

```
mlr --csv nest --implode --values --across-records -f count input1.csv input2.csv
```

Comment: @aburruso how would you use this with a lot of csv at same time? Kind of reading from a list of files like glob.glob?

Comment: @PauloSergioSchlogl the limit is in the limit on the number of open files for your platform. I needed to get it to 9000 files and used this mode https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues/299#issuecomment-576149958

Comment: Can I use some like this? 

input=$1

while IFS= read -r line;
do
mlr --csv nest --implode --values --across-records -f count $1;
done < "$input"